# Setting the date with Jcalender

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Anyone knows how to set the date with this calender?

http://tedserbinski.com/jcalendar/index.html

Answer (score 0):

i dont know exactly what you mean by setting the date.. do you mean set the default date?
if so.. you can set it throuigh the defaultDate option

Comment: Hmmm....I tried with this:

  $('fieldset.jcalendar').jcalendar({defaultDate:'2009-01-01 00:00:00'});

but that didnt work either....